# Whats the best way to expose current settings to your classes?

Tags: c++, architecture, design-patterns

Just as the title states, whats the best way to expose current settings like resolution to my classes?
(I know this might have been asked, but I couldn't find anything)

I was thinking of the service-locator design pattern, but I am unsure, as I read that it can be abused easily.( I mean it might not fit this particular use-case )

Comment: Comedy "just make them global" option.

Comment: You're right, I guess I am just complicating things.
Please post that as an answer(perhaps with more reasoning) and I'll accept it.

Comment: I bet a search on Stackoverflow would answer this, since it's not specifically gamedev related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just make them global until you determine that it's a detriment to your system.

Read this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork

Don't add complexity unless you're getting some benefit out of it.

Comment: This, 100x over. Also, viva c2.com.